# Haskell init list of n even/odd numbers

Tags: list, haskell

How can I init list of `n` `odd` or `even` elements, can I do something like so?

```
even_list :: Int -> [Int]
even_list n = [x | x <- [1..], even x, length n]
```

Comment: Have you tried? Did it work? If it didn't, what went wrong?

Comment: yep, doesn't work, cuz I cant just 'length n', as I understand - cond expected

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output? What do you mean by init? Haskell has an `init` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions with a step indicator to produce infinite lists with a certain step size, e.g. `[2,4..]` or `[1,3..]`.

When you want a finite list instead of an infinite list, you can use `take`, so a first attempt could be something like this:

```
Prelude> even_list n = take n [2,4..]
Prelude> even_list 15
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30]
```

If you want to go point-free and eliminate `n`, you can `flip` `take` so that instead of taking the length first, it takes it last:

```
Prelude> :t flip take
flip take :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
```

You can partially apply this with e.g. the odd numbers, to get this:

```
Prelude> odd_list = flip take [1,3..]
Prelude> odd_list 12
[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23]
```

Answer (score 1):

For now found solution, but I guess it's dirt and low speed

```
even_list n = takeWhile (< n * 2) [x | x <- [1..], even x]
odd_list n = takeWhile (<= n * 2) [x | x <- [1..], odd x]
```

Is where anything easier?